# Why does my vscode require me to write "python3" instead of just "python" to run a line of code

Tags: python, bash, github, path, zsh

I understand that the fact that having to type "python3" or "pip3" instead of "python" and "pip" respectively is an annoyance at worst, however it makes me paranoid that other things that I install to my vscode will also have to be run differently. Every other programmer that I watch doesn't have to do so.

```
zsh: command not found: python
```

Could it possibly be an issue with my pathing of my downloads?

Comment: The message means that there is neither an executable named `python` in any of the directories in your `path` array, nor is there a function or alias of that name defined in your shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, of course, has nothing to do with VSCode and everything to do with the install of Python on your machine. However, it is strange to not have the Python available with just `python` at the shell.

In any case, one simple way to solve this issue is to open (or create) `~/.zshrc` and add the following line:

```bash
alias python="python3"
```

This is a common thing in particular for macOS users, where `python` often points to the pre-installed Python2.7.

Restarting terminal/VSCode after making this change should fix your issue.

Comment: It's not that strange. As part of the transition from Python 2 to Python 3, some distributions stopped installing anything as `python` by default, in order to force the user to be explicit about which Python they want. I suspect over time, the use of `python` to represent Python 3 will become more common. (`python` is still used in virtual environments to refer to whatever version of Python was used to create the virtual environment.)